# Using scatter on 2 y axis with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-analysis

I'm trying to plot 2 different curves on matplotlib, but one of the plots needs to be scatter, or not have lines connecting the points. Is there anyway to do this? Right now, my code for my plotting is:

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax1.plot(epoch, list_of_gas, 'b')
ax2.plot(temp_times, temperatures, 'r')

ax1.set_ylabel('Pressure (torr)', color='b')
ax2.set_ylabel('Temperature (Celcius)', color='r')

ax1.set_title(folder + ' - ' + gas)
ax1.set_xlabel('time (seconds)')
ax1.set_xlim([0, 1000000])
ax2.set_ylim([0,425])
ax1.set_yscale('log')
ax1.set_ylim([ymin,ymax])

plt.show()
```

However, I want `ax1.scatter(epoch, list_of_gas, 'b')`, but you cannot use scatter with 2 axis. Does anyone know a way around this? Like to remove the lines connecting points?

Answer (score 10):

You can definitely have scatter plots in a twinx (dual axes, shared x-axis) situation:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x, y = np.random.random((2,50))
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax1.scatter(x, y, c='b')
ax2.plot(np.sort(x), np.arange(x.size), c='r')
```

[image: Scatter plot in dual axes with shared x-axis]

Also, if you wanted to remove the lines connecting the datapoints, you could add the option: `ls='none'`, or the longer `linestyle='none'`, as mentioned in the [matplotlib documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/lines_api.html?highlight=linestyle#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.set_linestyle). Remember that matplotlib, like most Python libraries, has chosen sensible defaults. For an ordinary call to `plot`, that default is `ls='-'` to produce a connected line.